# Не работает kotlinc

Tags: java, kotlin, компиляция

Я пытался скомпилировать первую программу kotlin:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    println("Hello, World!")
}
```

Запустил kotlinc app.kt -include-runtime -d app.jar

Это выводит следующий текст:

exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10936 out of bounds for length 10936
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(ClassReader.java:2464)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(ClassReader.java:2525)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:761)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:646)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:507)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.modules.JavaModuleInfo$Companion.read(JavaModuleInfo.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.access$findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:148)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:108)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:132)
    at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.ensureItemIterator(Sequences.kt:253)
    at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:240)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.none(_Sequences.kt:1239)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.addModularRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:227)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.computeRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.convertClasspathRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:223)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:401)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:282)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createEnvironmentWithScriptingSupport(K2JVMCompiler.kt:272)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:192)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:157)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:148)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:331)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.run(Preloader.java:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.main(Preloader.java:43)

Что мне делать?

Версия java - "13.0.2" 2020-01-14

Версия javac - javac 13.0.2

Версия kotlinc - kotlinc-jvm 1.2.0 (JRE 13.0.2+8)

Запускаю на linux mint x86_64

Comment: попробуйте обновить компилятор

Comment: Kotlin 1.2.0 вышел в конце 2017 года, а вы его пытаетесь с Java 13, которая вышла на два года позже, скрестить :)

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решилась установкой более старой версии java (jdk8)

Comment: Котлин надо апгрейдить, а не Java даунгрейдить.